# How to properly use factory in Nest.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I'm a newbie in nest.js and currently trying to create a factory for handle different types of error. How I can do that? I've read about dynamic modules from documentation (hard to understand yet), but can't implement my suggestions. What I want is:

1. Import my error factory to user module
2. Call my factory in case of error and set to the factory type of error and error message
3. The factory should accept these params and give back appropriate error service.

It would be very helpful if someone can explain such factory design in details or provide a guide for beginners. Thank you!

Comment: Try this article https://dev.to/nestjs/advanced-nestjs-dynamic-providers-1ee.
I think it will push you in the correct direction